# Passing every input name and value to ajax GET

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Today I am trying to loop through every textbox with an id of setting_value and set its name and value to a key value array, which I then pass to an ajax request.

The issue is, its only looking through the first occurence of the ID, does anyone know why?

This is the JS

```
function saveSettings() {
    var myFieldsValue = {};
    $("#setting_value").each(function() {
        myFieldsValue[this.name] = $(this).val();
        alert(this.name + ' = ' + $(this).val());
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '/' + 'api/ajax/higher/save_game_settings',
        type: "GET",
        data: myFieldsValue,
        statusCode: {
            400: function (response) {
                showErrorNotification("Something went wrong", response.responseText, 3000);
            },
            500: function (response) {
                showErrorNotification("Something went wrong", response.responseText, 3000);
            }
        },
        success: function(data) {
            showSuccessNotification("Action Completed", "Settings have been updated.", 1000);
        }
    });
}
```

This is the HTML

```
<div class="ibox-content" style="">
    <h2>Main Game Settings</h2>
    <p>Mainline In-Game configuration</p>
    <hr>
    @foreach($gameSettings as $key => $setting)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <b>{{ $setting->setting_key }}</b><br>
            {{ $setting->setting_description }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="setting_value" name="{{ $setting->setting_key }}" value="{{ $setting->setting_value }}" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    @endforeach
    <div class="btn btn-info" onclick="saveSettings();">Save Changes</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what does this have to do with PHP or C++?

Comment: It's written in a PHP framework @CoryKramer

Comment: You probably want to take a look at jQuery's [.seriaize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

Answer (score 3):

Element ids are expected to be unique.  They are unique identifiers.  As such `$("#setting_value")`  will only return a single element.  If you want to match against a group of elements, use a class instead such as

```
class="setting_value"
$(".setting_value")
```

Comment: I was in the middle of writing the same thing when your answer popped up. Missed it by 30 seconds.

Comment: Heh, been there.